# Curl range not working(downloads entire file)

Tags: bash, curl

```
curl -v -r 0-500 http://somefile -o localfile
```

It should download just the first 501 bytes, no?  Instead, it just downloads the entire thing.  All 67 megabytes.  Thanks curl!  Could my companies proxy servers be blocking this feature somehow?  I am skeptical about that, since the downloads themselves do work, just not the range feature.  Am I missing something?

Comment: which web server? does it accept ranges? Does web server return `Content-Length` when making a `HEAD` request—e.g., `curl -I http://somefile/`.

Comment: Its a national weather service data server, where this thing is routine and has worked for me before from other servers of mine.

curl -I http://somefile/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 17:54:11 GMT
ETag: "502c233-430cc73-523a4b19e5ce6"
Server: Apache
Expires: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 21:54:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=14400
Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 15:39:05 GMT
Content-Length: 70306931
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Comment: can you see the `Range` in your request headers when you use `-r` flag in curl? What would happen if you manually add the header—e.g., `curl -H "Range: bytes=0-500" ...`

Comment: curl -H "Range: bytes=0-500 :  No change.  still downloaded all 67MB

Answer (score 3):

As a client you could always abort the download when you have received what you want.

By using head, you will be able to limit the download to 500 bytes, even if the server does not accept the range-header

```
curl -v -r 0-500 http://somefile |head -c 500 > localfile
```

Comment: Would this work if I didnt necessarily want the first 500?  
Such as: curl -r 8000-50000

Comment: I guess you could do something like: curl...  | head -c 50000|tail -c 42000 > localfile, it will download the first 50000 bytes and then chop of the first 8000 that you don't want.   So not really, you will still waste bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

> It should download just the first 501 bytes, no?

It depends on the server. From `man curl`:

> You should also be aware that many HTTP/1.1 servers do not have this feature enabled, so that when you attempt to get a range, you'll instead get the whole document.

As you can see in the response from the server, it's using HTTP/1.1. So it's not surprising that the range feature is not supported at the server side.

Comment: It works on this server.  Other clients of mine have no problem doing this.  Its this particular client that is unable to handle -range

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following command

curl -H "range: bytes=354-500" -O http://example.com/file.extension